# Apache Redirect Working even when htaccess is removed

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

i was recently messing with .htaccess to remove .php, reditect and internally redirect to php

but now when i go to my browser without .php even then it is getting redirected internally to file.php even when i have a2dismod rewrite executed

Can someone assist me.Thnx

tried this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^about$ 1.php?%1 [NC,L]
```

still didnt work....

if someone could provide a working code for removing .php and redirecting internally and to ignore a few certain files like go.php,now.php etc that would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^index.php$)^.*$ /%1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: You need to provide more details in your comment pls, like what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^about$ 1.php?%1 [NC,L]

Comment: i tried that .... still didnt work then i removed MultiViews from the options in sites enabled then i got 500 error

Comment: Provide your complete .htaccess in your question (not in comments).

Comment: Thanks for your .htaccess. Now tell me which URL did you use to test the code?

Comment: Besides if you really want to do this: `.htaccess to remove .php, reditect and internally redirect to php` I can provide you a working code.

Comment: is it possible to ignore specific files like                             RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index.php

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers cache server redirects in a client-side manner.
Try different browser (or Chrome's Incognito mode / Firefox's private browsing).

Unfortunately, usually there's no easy way to control such cache from either client-side or server-side.

Comment: how to avoid a certain no. of files like index.php and more.php